# How to enable Entity Framework in a ASP.NET WebForms Website Project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

How do you enable Entity Framework in a WebForms Website Project (not Web Application Project) in Visual Studio 2012?

Edit 1: I'm using Framework 4.0. I have installed Entity Framework 5.0 using the Package Manager Console. When executing Enable-Migrations in Package Manager Console it throws and error.

```
PM> enable-migrations
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Server stack trace: 
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio (if any) are you using, and what is the latest version of .NET Framework you have installed?  These will determine what level of EF support you current have.  You can also download updates to EF separately.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 (says in question). I have all Frameworks installed. I need it to work with Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether you have installed Entity Framework or not. If not Please get EF Runtime Available on NuGet

Check these Links for [Nuget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx) and [Sample Application](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/)

Comment: I have installed Entity Framework 5.0 using the Package Manager Console.